# Different user interfaces for landscape and portrait orientations

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, interface, landscape, portrait

I've long been a question to which I have not found a good answer.

Is it possible (it must! ;) to build different user interfaces for example the landscape and portrait or iPhone with 3,5" oder 4" display.

Like saying in code, THIS IS the landscape interface and THIS IS the portrait interface...

I hope there is a simple way to this. :)

With best regards from Munich, Germany

Laurenz

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it. I made a function called `configureViewForOrientation:` that takes as a parameter the orientation that you want to set up the interface for.

```
-(void)configureViewForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
    {
        //set up portrait interface
    }

    else
    { 
        //set up landscape interface
    }
}
```

You can call this method from your `viewDidLoad` (or wherever you initially set up your interface) and feed it the current orientation using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureViewForOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation];
}
```

You can also call it when your device is rotated:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self configureViewForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

There are a couple caveats (such as whether you're checking device orientation immediately upon app launch) but this should work for the majority of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer how will you setup interface depends upon the orientation.. Sorry it may be ease but i am very new to ios . Any help is much appreciated